# Entire function doesn't cut real axis.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let be $ f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ a entire function. If it verifies that $ f(\mathbb{C}) \cap \mathbb{R} = \emptyset $ then we cand deduce that $ f $ is constant* (see below to proof), but my question is, the same statement is true if $ f( \mathbb{C} ) \cap [0, \infty) = \emptyset $? And generally, if $ f(\mathbb{C}) \cap [a,b] = \emptyset $ then $ f $ must be constant?

I have test some entire functions for the case $ [0, \infty) $ like $ \sin(z) $ and $ \cos(z) $ but I haven't found a conterexpample. I haven't found any similar way to proced like in the case $ f(\mathbb{C}) \cap \mathbb{R} $.

*Proof:

From $ f( \mathbb{C}) \cap \mathbb{R} = \emptyset $ we deduce that $ \Im(f(z)) > 0 \ \forall z \in \mathbb{C} \ $ or $ \ \Im(f(z)) < 0 \ \forall z \in \mathbb{C} $, because $ f $ is continuous and then $ f( \mathbb{C} ) $ must be a connected subset of $ \mathbb{C} $.

Now we consider the compositions $ e^{if} = e^{-v + iu} $ and $ e^{-if} = e^{v - iu} $ where $ f = u + iv $. This functions must be also entire, and we have
$$
| e^{if} |=
|e^{-v + iu}| =
e^{-v}
\ \ \mbox{ and } \ \
| e^{-if} |=
|e^{v - iu}| =
e^{v}
$$
So, if $ v(z) = \Im(f(z)) > 0 \ \forall z \in \mathbb{C} $, the first equality gives that $ |e^{if(z)}| \leq 1 $. In the same way, if $ v(z) = \Im(f(z)) < 0 $, the second equality gives that $ |e^{-if(z)}| \leq 1 $.

As $ e^{if} $ and $ e^{-if} $ are entire bounded functions, they must be constant. So we deduce $ f $ is a constant function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f(z) \notin [0,+\infty)$ for every $z\in \mathbb{C}$, consider the function defined by $g(z) = \sqrt{f(z)}$, where you use your favourite branch of the square root on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,+\infty)$. Then $g$ has image in either the upper or the lower half-plane, hence is constant by what you already know. But then $f(z) = g(z)^2$ is constant too.

If $f(\mathbb{C}) \subseteq \mathbb{C}\setminus [a,b]$, where $a \neq b$ and $[a,b]$ denotes the segment between the two points, consider the function defined by

$$h(z) = \frac{f(z)-a}{b-f(z)}\,.$$

Then $h$ is an entire function with $h(\mathbb{C}) \subseteq \mathbb{C} \setminus [0,+\infty)$. So $h$ is constant by the previous, and $f$ is constant because

$$f(z) = \frac{bh(z)+a}{h(z)+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I have looking for!

Comment: Can you please explain to me why $h(\Bbb C)\subseteq \Bbb C\setminus [0,+\infty)$?

Comment: @Holo The Möbius transformation $T\colon w \mapsto \frac{w-a}{b-w}$ maps the straight line through $a$ and $b$, plus $\{\infty\}$, to $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$. For $T(a) = 0,\, T(b) = \infty$, and $T\bigl(\frac{1}{2}(a+b)\bigr) = 1$. Since the midpoint is mapped to a positive real number (namely $1$), it follows that the segment $[a,b]$ is mapped to $[0,+\infty) \cup \{\infty\}$. Since Möbius transformations are bijective on the sphere, it follows that $T$ maps $(\mathbb{C}\setminus [a,b]) \cup \{\infty\}$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks

Answer (score 4):

This question and more general variants of it are answered by a [celebrated theorem by Picard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem).

Comment: It is posible to find a more elementary proof?